# Как сделать поиск по двум параметрам

Tags: php, mysql

Товар ищется по названию. Как сделать так чтобы искался не только по названию "title" но и по айди товара "products_id"?

```html
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_products WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' AND visible = '1'",$link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' AND visible='1' ORDER BY $sorting $qury_start_num ",$link);
```

Comment: Что значит "но и по Id". вам надо что бы совпадали оба условия или хотя бы одно из них. есть ли какой то приоритет в поиске/выдаче. Но вообще надо просто добавить в sql запрос еще одно условие в часть where

Comment: Чтобы совпадало оба условия. То есть чтобы можно было в поиске искать и по названию и по айди

Comment: Если оба значит используйте 'AND' в условии.

Comment: @Mike Пробовал WHERE title and products_id - не работает

Comment: Вы бы пару примеров запросов посмотрели, например тут http://oracleplsql.ru/where.html  AND как и в любых других языках программирования это логический оператор, слева и справа от которого задаются полные _условия_. А _условие_ это сравнение двух значений т.е. состоит как минимум из 3х компонент "что сравниваем", "оператор сравнения", "с чем сравниваем"

Comment: @Mike city = 'New York' AND name = 'Intel' мол так? Не пойму ничего, тупень в этом...

Comment: да так. ну или вместо = ваши like. И кстати у вас же даже в существующем запросе проверяются два условия (вы там еще visible проверяете). по аналогии добавляете еще одно. Только что то мне подсказывает, что "совпало оба условия" это совершенно не то что надо. Как минимум надо видимо динамически строить текст запроса. Ведь пользователь может не знать id и его не укажет а значит и проверять его в этом случае не надо будет

Comment: @Mike а что мне нужно тогда писать вместо "city" и "name"? Просто пользователь будет помимо по названию товара искать и по айди, так задумано.... Мол написал "721" и появился товар с этим айди.